# How can I provide multiple conditions for data trigger in WPF?

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

How can I provide multiple conditions for data trigger in WPF?

Answer (score 311, accepted):

Use [MultiDataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger.aspx) type

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Value="WA">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
      </DataTrigger>    
      <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
          <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Value="Portland" />
          <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Value="OR" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan" />
      </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do an "OR" statement in the multiTrigger.  e.g. the name = "portland" OR the state = "OR"

Comment: @jasonk - Not sure if you can do that with a MultiTrigger. You can define two triggers for that..

Comment: If it's a simple OR condition statement, you can reverse the logic so it turns into an AND. 
|condition1 |condition2 | result |
|true       |true       | true   |
|true       |false      | true   |
|false      |true       | true   |
|false      |false      | false  |
instead of checking for either/OR are true, check when both/AND are false, and set the default to true.

Comment: @WeSamAbdallah You can't check for conditions being false.

Comment: You can check for a condition being false by a simple converter.

Comment: @Paul How about <Condition Value="False">?

Answer (score 58):

@jasonk - if you want to have "or" then negate all conditions since (A and B) <=> ~(~A or ~B)

but if you have values other than boolean try using type converters:

```
<MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Value="True">
        <Condition.Binding>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource conditionConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Name" />
                <Binding Path="State" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Condition.Binding>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan" />
    </Condition>
</MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
```

you can use the values in Convert method any way you like to produce a condition which suits you.

Comment: Ah, smart move to negate everything and flip it to an OR condition :)

Comment: Could you please expand on this answer a little bit? I'm not sure how to use it. What does the `conditionConverter` do? How are we specifying "Portland" and "OR" as our two `or` options in this example?

Comment: @cod3monk3y, your link is broken.

Answer (score 21):

To elaborate on [@serine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660030/1174169) and illustrate working with non-trivial multi-valued condition: I had a need to show a "dim-out" overlay on an item for the boolean condition `NOT a AND (b OR NOT c)`.

> For background, this is a "Multiple Choice" question. If the user picks a wrong answer it becomes **disabled** (dimmed out and cannot be selected again). An automated agent has the ability to **focus** on any particular choice to give an explanation (border highlighted). When the agent focuses on an item, it should not be dimmed out *even if it is disabled*. All items that are not in focused are marked **de-focused**, and should be dimmed out.
>
> The logic for dimming is thus:
>
> `NOT IsFocused AND (IsDefocused OR NOT Enabled)`

To implement this logic, I made a generic `IMultiValueConverter` named (awkwardly) to match my logic

```
// 'P' represents a parenthesis
//     !  a &&  ( b ||  !  c )
class NOT_a_AND_P_b_OR_NOT_c_P : IMultiValueConverter
{
    // redacted [...] for brevity
    public object Convert(object[] values, ...)
    {
        bool a = System.Convert.ToBoolean(values[0]);
        bool b = System.Convert.ToBoolean(values[1]);
        bool c = System.Convert.ToBoolean(values[2]);

        return !a && (b || !c);
    }
    ...
}
```

In the XAML I use this in a `MultiDataTrigger` in a `<Style><Style.Triggers>` resource

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <!-- when the equation is TRUE ... -->
        <Condition Value="True">
            <Condition.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NOT_a_AND_P_b_OR_NOT_c_P}">
                    <!-- NOT IsFocus AND ( IsDefocused OR NOT Enabled ) -->
                    <Binding Path="IsFocus"/>
                    <Binding Path="IsDefocused" />
                    <Binding Path="Enabled" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Condition.Binding>
        </Condition>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        <!-- ... show the 'dim-out' overlay -->
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

And for completeness sake, my converter is defined in a `ResourceDictionary`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:My.Converters" ...>
    <conv:NOT_a_AND_P_b_OR_NOT_c_P x:Key="NOT_a_AND_P_b_OR_NOT_c_P" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the intent of converters to be used this way. They are really meant for converting values for display. When it gets this complicated, just create a calculated property on the view model that gives you what you need.

Comment: That naming though

Comment: Please take a moment of silence to remember when programming was a craft and code was elegant.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS ANSWER IS FOR ANIMATIONS ONLY**
**If you wanna implement the AND logic, you should use MultiTrigger, here is an example:**
Suppose we want to do some actions if the property Text="" (empty string) **AND** IsKeyboardFocused="False", then your code should look like the following:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="Text" Value="" />
        <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="False" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
            <!-- Your actions here -->
        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
</MultiTrigger>
```

**If you wanna implement the OR logic, there are couple of ways, and it depends on what you try to do:**

The first option is to use multiple Triggers. 
So, suppose you wanna do something if either Text="" **OR** IsKeyboardFocused="False", 
then your code should look something like this:

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" 
            Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
</Trigger>
```

But the problem in this is what will I do if i wanna do something if either Text ISN'T null **OR** IsKeyboard="True"? This can be achieved by the second approach: 
Recall De Morgan's rule, that says !(!x && !y) = x || y. 
So we'll use it to solve the previous problem, by writing a multi trigger that it's triggered when Text="" and IsKeyboard="True", and we'll do our actions in **EXIT ACTIONS**, like this:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="Text" Value="" />
        <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="False" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
        <!-- Do something here -->
    </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiTrigger>
```