# Combine different style triggers (like &&)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I tried to change the behaviour of my textboxes so that they change their borderbrush if someone hovers over them. At the same time I want my textboxes to stay green bordered if someone types in it. 
I first tried the hover over thing and created this piece of code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="TextBox.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TextBox.IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The problem comes by adding the triggers for the `IsKeyboardFocused` event. If i add these two extra triggers, everything is working except the hover over parts. So my textbox won't get a green border if i hover over it.

Is there anyway to solve this or combine two triggers like `If IsMouseOver==true && IsKeyboardFocused == false then borderbrush = green` ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need MultiDataTriggers. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905932/how-to-provide-multiple-conditions-for-data-trigger-in-wpf

Comment: @AntonTykhyy: Post an answer...

Comment: yes he should do this if he wants rep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MultiTrigger` triggers on a logical-AND combination of conditions. There is no logical-OR `MultiTrigger`, though.